# Planar graph with 9 vertices and 3 components property

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have been preparing for graph theory exams and found a statement that:

Let $G$ be a planar graph with 9 vertices and 3 components. Then complement of graph $G$ is not a planar graph.

How can we try to prove it using theorems from graph theory?

Comment: When you say basic theorems of graph theory", what basic theorems are those? You must know some theorems that are relevant to, say, whether graphs are planar. Have you tried applying those?

Comment: To start with, there can't be two components with as many as $3$ vertices, or the complement would contain a $K_{3,3}$

Comment: @saulspatz And then the graph $G$ would not be planar?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the theorem is true if two components have cardinality at least $3$, so it's enough to consider the case where that's not so.

Comment: I can do the case where two components have cardinality $2$ so are paths of length $1$.  The complement of these two components is a $C_4$ and each of the other $5$ vertices must be adjacent to all $4$ of its vertices.  This is plainly impossible in a planar graph.  So, we can assume one component has either $6$ or $7$ vertices.

Comment: I have confirmed that the theorem is true by computer search using [nauty](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).  I know this doesn't answer the OP's question, but I wanted to warn against wasting time looking for a counterexample.

Comment: @saulspatz Not only is it bad if two components have $3$ or more vertices; the same argument works when there is a single component of order between $3$ and $6$ (so that its complement also has order between $3$ and $6$).

Comment: @MishaLavrov Good point!  I believe I have a proof in the final case, where there are $2$ isolated vertices and a component of order $7$, but it's rather awkward.  I'm trying to refine it.

Answer (score 2):

With $3$ components and $9$ vertices, there must be a component $C$ with at least $3$ vertices. If $C$ contains between $3$ and $6$ vertices, there is a $K_{3,3}$ formed in $G'$ (the complement of $G$) by taking three vertices in $C$ and three outside $C$. Also, $C$ cannot contain more than $7$ vertices, because there are two other components with at least one vertex each.

So it remains to consider the case when $C$ has order $7$, and $G$ has two vertices $x,y$ not in $C$. In $G'$, $x$ and $y$ are adjacent to every vertex of $C$.

If $G'[C]$ (the subgraph of $G'$ induced by $C$) contains a cycle, then $G'$ contains a subdivision of $K_5$ whose key vertices are $x$, $y$, and three vertices on the cycle. So $G'$ is not planar.

If $G'[C]$ contains a vertex $z$ of degree $3$ or more, then $G'$ contains a $K_{3,3}$: put $x,y,z$ on one side, and the neighbors of $z$ on the other side. So $G'$ is not planar.

Otherwise, $G'[C]$ is a forest in which all vertices have degree at most $2$: a forest in which all trees are paths. As a result, it is a subgraph of the path on $7$ vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_6, v_7$ connected in that order. But now each of $v_1, v_2, v_3$ is connected to each of $v_5, v_6, v_7$ in $G$, forming a $K_{3,3}$ in $G$. So $G$ is not planar, contrary to assumption!

Therefore $G$ and $G'$ cannot both be planar.

Comment: What does it mean that $G'[C]$ is a forest of maximum degree 2 - does it mean that there are at most 2 trees in this in this forest or rather every vertex has maximum degree 2?

Comment: It means maximum degree $2$ since the case where there is a vertex of degree $3$ or more has already been disposed of.

Comment: Excellent.  I really ought to delete my answer, but I worked so hard on it that I just can't bring myself to do so.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't understand one more thing - why when $G'[C]$ contains a cycle then $G'$ contains a subdivision of $K_5$? I understand that when $G'[C]$ contains a 3-cycle then $G'$ contains a subdivision of $K_5$. But what about cycles with more vertices?

Comment: @avan1235 Any cycle is a subdivision of $K_3$, which becomes a subdivision of $K_5$ when you add $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, if two of the components of $G$ each have at least $3$ vertices, then the complement $G'$ contains a $K_{3,3}$ and is nonplanar.  Furthermore as pointed out by Misha Lavrov, if there is a component with between $3$ and $6$ vertices, then we can pick $3$ vertices in the component and $3$ in the complement to get a $K_{3,3}$

The only remaining case is when two of the components are isolated vertices and the remaining component, $C$ has order $7$.  Let the isolated vertices be $a$ and $b$ and suppose $C$ has a vertex $c$ of degree less than $4$.  Then there are distinct vertices $x,y,z\neq c$ in $C$ to which $c$ is not adjacent to.  Then in $G'$ each of $a,b,c$ is adjacent to each of $x,y,z$ so $G'$ is nonplanar.

We may therefore assume that every vertex of $C$ has degree at least $4$.  Since $C$ is planar, it has at most $3(7-2)=15$ edges, so $C'$ has at least $21-15=6$ edges.  In $G'$, each of the isolated vertices is adjacent to every vertex in $C$, and the two isolated vertices are adjacent to each other, giving at least $6+7+7+1=21$ edges in $G'$.  But a planar graph on $9$ vertices has at most $3(9-2)=21$ edges, so in fact $C$ has $15$ edges, and the sum of its vertex degrees is $30.$  That leaves only two possible degree sequences for $C$: $6,4,4,4,4,4,4$ or $5,5,4,4,4,4,4.$

I have arguments disposing of both of these cases, or at least I think I do, but they are long and consist of showing that a planar graph with either degree sequence cannot exist, by trying to construct one, and verifying that the attempt must fail.  It doesn't seem worthwhile to type them here.  I started typing the case where one vertex has degree $6$, but quit in the middle because I didn't think anyone would read it.

It seems to me that once we know the minimum degree of $C$ is $4$, there ought to be a way of showing it has a $K_5$ minor, but I can't see how to do it.